# What does 1. mean in a mathematica solution (of a sum)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to evaluate a difficult sum: mathematica seems to evaluate it, giving the message "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result"

The solution contains expressions "1." such as (0.5 + 1.i).

What does the 1. mean?

Comment: @Orbling You are wrong: `FullForm[(0.5 + 1.i)]` gives ``Plus[0.5`,Times[1.`,i]]`` and so `.` just means here that ``1.`` is a [machine-number](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MachinePrecision.html).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Fair enough.

Comment: Sorry some of the comments here are off (or likely coming from non mathematica people). Lack of extra zeros does not indicate low precision, eg 1 // N produces 1. , even though that value is good to machine precision. You might try to plug 1/2 + i back in your system to see if its exact.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750368/trying-to-solve-system-of-equations-with-mathematica/18759358#18759358). Mathematica interprets the input 0.5 (or any input containing 0.5), for example, as "numerical," and so its attempts to solve it will be numerical in nature, assuming that 0.5 is some real number that is within whatever relevant level of precision that it looks like it's equal to 0.5. Even though 0.5==1/2 will return True, Mathematica still treats those two expressions very differently.

If you input some commands using "numerical" (ie. decimal) numbers, Mathematica falls to numerical methods (like NIntegrate, NSolve, NDSolve, numerical versions of arithmetic operations, etc.) rather than those that apply to integers, rationals, etc.

The error that occurs is due to how NSolve (or another such algorithm) works. But it then takes the step of making the equations exact (it does know, after all, that 0.5=1/2) and then gets an exact solution, but then it "numericizes" the result (hits it with an N command) to give you the numerical equivalent.

Type in N[1/2+I] and see what you get. Should be 0.5+1.i. All this means is that you have a quantity that is roughly 1.0000000000000000 in the imaginary direction and 0.50000000000000 in the real direction.

To see the difference explicitly, try:

```
Head[1]
Head[1.]
```

The decimal point indicates to Mathematica that the second of the two is a "real" number, i.e. for floating point arithmetic of some sort. The first one is an integer, for which Mathematica sometimes uses different sorts of algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The "1." is there to guarantee that subsequent use of that expression doesn't lose that the expression was obtained numerically, and is therefore subject to numerical precision.  For example,

```
In[121]:= Pi/3.14`2 * x
Out[121]= 1.0 x
```

Even though you might think that `1.0*x == x`, it's certainly not true that `Pi==3.14`; rather, `Pi` is only `3.14` to the given precision of 2.  By including the `1.0` in the answer (which `InputForm` shows is actually internally 1.00050721451904243263141509021640261145`2) the next evaluation,

```
In[122]:= % /. x -> 3
Out[122]= 3.0
```

comes out correct instead of incorrectly giving an exact `3`.