# Trying to Solve System of Equations with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm attempting to solve a system of equations with mathematica.  Here's my code.

```
f1[TA_, TB_] := TA - TB + C
f2[TA_, TB_] := 
TA*(TB - TA) + TA*TB + 0.5*TA^2 + TB*(TB - TA) + 0.5*TB^2
Solve[{f1[TA, TB] == 0, f2[TA, TB] == 0}, {TA, TB}]
```

The output that Mathematica gives me is weird, and I think it's wrong (the T variables represent time, so they can't be negative).  [You can see the output here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y73Ey.jpg)

What does 0.-1.5C mean?  Does it mean -1.5C?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess it will depend on the value of `C`. If `C < 0` then your solution will be positive.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Just to be sure, 0.-1.5C means -1.5 * C then?  Also, I'm using Solve correctly?

Comment: Yes to both as far as I know. I would advice using lower case for your variables in order to avoid conflicts with built-in symbols.

Comment: 0.5 is treated as an inexact real value. use 1/2 and that pesky 0. will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 0.-1.5C means -3C/2, but written in the language of "Real" rather than "Rational." Your input uses decimals, which Mathematica interprets as approximate/numerical data, not exact rationals. "0." represents the floating point real number that's just about as close to zero as Mathematica can figure. But you can check:

```
Head[0.]
Head[0]
```

.. and you'll find that 0. is a real but 0 is an integer. There is a similar distinction between 0.5 and 1/2.

I believe there are a few ways to improve this, at least one of which has already been mentioned.

First, capital C is a built-in symbol. Better, generally, to use lowercase letters for n, c, d, etc.

Second, these functions do not require delayed evaluation, so the := is superfluous.

However, that's not really part of the issue. Even correcting these minor issues:

```
f1[ta_, tb_] = ta - tb + c;
f2[ta_, tb_] = ta*tc + ta*tb + 0.5*ta^2 + tb*tc + 0.5*tb^2;
Solve[{f1[ta, tb] == 0, f2[ta, tb] == 0}, {ta, tb}]
```

...will still lead to the same error. Why? Well, Mathematica solves nonlinear equations in a particular way such that (when presented with "numerical" data, i.e. equations with 0.5 instead of 1/2 in them), it tries to solve them numerically (same as NSolve).

However, solving equations numerically is different than doing so symbolically. The numerical algorithms can have issues for systems that can be solved symbolically, as we see here. I don't know enough about NSolve to know why this error is produced, it would depend on the algorithms being used by NSolve, but it may have to do with the fact that the Jacobian of this system near the solution could be zero (depending on tc).

When a numerical algorithm behaves awkwardly, it might be an indication that converting the system to an exact one (which is what it does) will help. (Indeed, replacing all 0.5 with 1/2 will make the error go away.)

Another option is to use FindRoot instead, but only in the case that there are no other symbols like tc or c here. (If you fix c=1 and tc=2, or any other values, FindRoot will run without error, while Solve or NSolve will still produce the same error with a solution that is nonetheless valid.)

One thing that might be meaningful / useful to you is this:

```
f1[ta_, tb_] = ta - tb + c;
f2[ta_, tb_] = ta*tc + ta*tb + 0.5*ta^2 + tb*tc + 0.5*tb^2;
SOL = Solve[{f1[ta, tb] == 0, f2[ta, tb] == 0}, {ta, tb}]
Reduce[ReplaceAll[{ta >= 0, tb >= 0}, SOL[[1]]], {ta, tb}]
Reduce[ReplaceAll[{ta >= 0, tb >= 0}, SOL[[2]]], {ta, tb}]
```

The two additional lines take the two solutions to this equation and check whether ta and tb are non-negative, since this is something you're interested in. For this, the output is:

```
{{ta -> 0. - 0.5 c, tb -> 0. + 0.5 c}, {ta -> -0.5 c - 1. tc, tb -> 0.5 c - 1. tc}}
c == 0
(tc < 0 && 2. tc <= c <= -2. tc) || (tc == 0 && c == 0)
```

One solution is (-0.5c,0.5c), and the other is (-0.5c-tc,0.5c-tc)

The output also includes three ratnz errors, which we can gleefully ignore.

The rest of the output tells us that the first solution (-0.5c,0.5c) is valid (ta and tb >= 0) only when c=0 which should be obvious. The second solution is valid when tc<0 and tc <= c <= -2 tc (or when c=tc=0, which is the degenerate solution that includes both cases).

In the end, if ratnz is an issue, start your code with:

```
Off["ratnz"];
```

That should suppress the error, assuming you are comfortable with the fact that sometimes Mathematica will make this maneuver to solve equations that are input as if they are numerical, but are better solved symbolically.